Mail delivery records | SF Core
I'm working on a project where the client wants to keep a record of the emails that have been sent (this email is sent after the user is enabled, under certain conditions, to click the button). The purpose of the use case is to keep a record of the time it takes for the department receiving the email to respond from SF. Do you have any ideas? They suggested the option of creating a task after the user clicks the send email button. If this would work, how should I do it? Thanks in advance, regards!
